# ADO.NET c# , insert query with more id's

Tags: c#, insert, ado.net

Im new to ado.net in c#. I need to add a couple of Id's(primary keys) that will be placed in one table.These primary keys have already a value from other tables so i nedd to grab them and fill them in. The the next columns will be filled in by user => firstname,lastname,dateOfBirth,securitynumber. And i need to add the id keywords also. i have no clue how to start with it. I just know how to do an insert. So i have to get the addressId and @vehicleid,@fuelcardid from somwhere but i dont get it how?

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO [Driver] (firstName,lastName,dateOfBirth,addressId,securityNumber,vehicleid,fuelcardid) Values (@firstName,@lastName,@dateOfBirth,@addressId,@securityNumber,@vehicleid,@fuelcardid);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
            int? newdriverID= null;
            SqlConnection connection = getConnection();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
                SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                try {
                    SqlParameter parDriverFirstName = new SqlParameter();
                    parDriverFirstName.ParameterName = "@firstName";
                    parDriverFirstName.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parDriverFirstName);

                    SqlParameter parDriverLastName = new SqlParameter();
                    parDriverLastName.ParameterName = "@lastName";
                    parDriverLastName.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parDriverLastName);

                    SqlParameter parDriverDateOfBirth = new SqlParameter();
                    parDriverDateOfBirth.ParameterName = "@dateOfBirth";
                    parDriverDateOfBirth.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parDriverDateOfBirth);

                    SqlParameter parAddressId = new SqlParameter();
                    parAddressId.ParameterName = "@addressId";
                    parAddressId.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parAddressId);

                    SqlParameter parDriverSecurityNr = new SqlParameter();
                    parDriverSecurityNr.ParameterName = "@securityNumber";
                    parDriverSecurityNr.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parDriverSecurityNr);

                    SqlParameter parvehicleId = new SqlParameter();
                    parvehicleId.ParameterName = "@vehicleid";
                    parvehicleId.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parvehicleId);

                    SqlParameter parFuelCardID = new SqlParameter();
                    parFuelCardID.ParameterName = "@fuelcardid";
                    parFuelCardID.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parFuelCardID);

                    command.Parameters["@firstName"].Value = driver.FirstName;
                    command.Parameters["@lastName"].Value = driver.LastName;
                    command.Parameters["@dateOfBirth"].Value = driver.DateOfBirth;
                    command.Parameters["@securityNumber"].Value = driver.SecurityNumber;

                    command.Parameters["@addressId"].Value = addressId;
                    command.Parameters["@vehicleid"].Value = vehicleid; //TODO test if this works
                    command.Parameters["@fuelcardid"].Value = fuelcardid;

                    connection.Open();
                    newdriverID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                    transaction.Commit();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                } finally {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            if(newdriverID != null) {
                foreach (string licensetype in driver.DriversLicenceType) {
                    //if a driver has no license type this will simply not loop once
                    //inserts a driverid and typeid into the DriversLicenceType table that can be used elsewhere
                    if (Alldriverlicensetypes.ContainsValue(licensetype)) {
                        string insertLicenseQuery = "INSERT INTO [DriverLicenseType] (driverId,licenseTypeId) Values (@driverid,@licenseID)";
                        SqlConnection licenseconnection = getConnection();
                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertLicenseQuery, licenseconnection)) {
                            SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                            command.Transaction = transaction;
                            try {

                                SqlParameter pardriverId = new SqlParameter();
                            pardriverId.ParameterName = "@driverid";
                            pardriverId.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
                            command.Parameters.Add(pardriverId);
                            command.Parameters["@driverid"].Value = newdriverID;

                            SqlParameter parlicenseID = new SqlParameter();
                            parlicenseID.ParameterName = "@licenseID";
                            parlicenseID.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
                            command.Parameters.Add(parlicenseID);
                            int key = Alldriverlicensetypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == licensetype).Key;
                            command.Parameters["@driverid"].Value = key;

                            connection.Open();
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            transaction.Commit();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                        } finally {
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    } else {
                        //trying to add a type that is not in the database => ASK what to do here?
                    }
                }
            }//if the previous insert failed, the id will be null so dont add anything

        }
```

Comment: If your ID is an autoincrement, it will be generated for you and you don't need to supply it.

Comment: Its not autoincrement

Comment: Why not? If you want a unique ID for your primary key, that is the easiest way to ensure the values are unique. Otherwise, I really don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: The other ID's have already a value. I need to get them from their original table and fill them in this query

Comment: Sounds like you need a joined `insert` then. Without the definitions of these tables we cannot advise. Side points: you really need `using` on the connection and transaction objects (and then you can remove the `try` `catch` `Rollback` code as it is done automatically). You can shorten adding parameters to `command.Parameters.Add(@firstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = driver.FirstName;`. You should consider using `SqlBulkCopy` or a Table parameter instead of looping `insertLicenseQuery`